# Quasi-compact surjective morphism of smooth k-schemes is flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

In the article "The Greenberg functor revisited'' (https://doi.org/10.1007/s40879-017-0210-0) by Bertapelle and González-Avilés, one can read, before the statement of Theorem A.12, that a given morphism, call it $f\colon X\to Y$ "is a quasi-compact [even affine] and surjective morphism of smooth $k$-schemes [$k$ is a field] and therefore faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation.''  This might be trivial, but I have no idea how to prove flatness: the most general result of this kind which I have been able to find in the literature is EGA IV.15.4.2, which however requires one of the following conditions (I am keeping the same notation as in EGA), none of which I am able to deduce from the information above:

- $f$ is universally open;
- for any $x\in X$, $f$ is open at the generic points of the irreducible components of $X_{f(x)}$ containing $x$;
- for any $x\in X$, $\dim\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\dim\mathcal{O}_{f(x)}+\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{f(x)}}\kappa(f(x)))$

I would be grateful for an explanation of why $f$ is flat.

Comment: Most of the time, the definition of a smooth morphism includes flatness. What definition are you using?

Comment: `f` is a morphism _between_ smooth schemes over the base field, but this does not imply that it is smooth, right?

Comment: Sorry, I misread! Certainly there are many non-smooth morphisms between smooth schemes. For instance, $\Bbb A^2\to\Bbb A^1$ by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is non-smooth, quasi-compact, and surjective. (And you had it right the first time - dollar signs for math mode work in the comments and are preferred.) Are there perhaps other assumptions or parts of the setup from the paper that aren't included in your question?

Comment: No problem! I am fine with your example, but I was asking about flatness.

Comment: I have now posted this question on MathOverflow (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406588/quasi-compact-surjective-morphism-of-smooth-k-schemes-is-flat).